# Can a single variable function equal a multivariable one?

Tags: real-analysis

In the book *'Calculus, Early Transcendentals' by James Stewart*, the author writes at some point:

$$ g(x)=f(x,b) $$
when taking the partial of $f$ with respect to $x$. Now, this is a reasonable thing to assume (In fact, when I take partial derivatives I think exactly like that). That made me ask the question: can multi-variable function ever equal a single variable one ? $f(x,b)$ is  a function that takes as input order tuples $(x,b)$ (with $b$ being a constant) and outputs a real value. On the other hand, $g(x)$ takes only a real value and outputs a real value. The domains of the two functions could look for example like:

$$ D_{f} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R \times\{ b\}  | \ x\in\mathbb R \} , \ b\in\mathbb R $$
and
$$ D_g = \mathbb R$$
Obviously, $D_{f} \neq D_g $ (The former contains tuples while the latter does not) which means that they can't be equal functions.

Comment: That question is unclear for me. What do you mean that they are "the same"? Because using standard definitions, you already answered yourself, that they can't be equal.

Comment: you could simply define $f(x,b)=g(x)$ where $f:X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ and $g:X\rightarrow Z$ for arbitrary sets $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: The equality of functions is between the function $g$ and the function $f\circ h$, which is the composition of $f$ and the one-variable function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $h(x)=(x,b)$.

Comment: @enedil I asked as I could be missing some special case out there where $ f $ and $g$ are equal functions.

Comment: @PinkPanther Nice, but for two function to be equal they have to have the same domain right ? How can ever $X \times Y = X $ ?

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis If you want to speak of equality, you need some definition for what it means to be equal. If you require the same domain, then you already answered the question yourself. But usually one defines equality modulo some relation. For real vector spaces this relation would be isomorphisms of real vector spaces...
For functions we can only look at the domain and codomain. So the kind of "equality" you are looking for could include the requirement that $f(x,b)=g(x)$ for all $b$ in the appropriate domains, respectively.

Comment: Oh great. Now it is more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are misleading. The answer to your question:

> Can a single variable function equal a multivariable one?

is **no** taken literally. You cannot set a multivariable *function* to be equal to a single variable *function* --- but this is not what the equation is saying. The equation
$$
g(x) = f(x, b)
$$

should be understood as saying: **for all values of $x$, the value of $g(x)$ is equal to the value $f(x, b)$.**
So it is not a statement about equality between two functions, but equality of real numbers. And of course it is totally fine to write a statement of equality between real numbers.

More generally, when we write equations between applications of functions of one or more variables ($x$ and $y$ etc.), we generally mean this should hold for all values of the variables. So for instance, $\sin (-x) = \sin x$ is an equation of two functions of $x$, which should hold for all values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, and Pink Panther's comment makes it clear why.

You might find it instructive to observe that good Computer Algebra Systems allow for this, e.g. http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/226#1986

'IsUnivariate(f) : RngMPolElt -> BoolElt, RngUPolElt, RngIntElt

Given a multivariate polynomial f∈R[x1, ..., xn], this function returns whether f is in fact a univariate polynomial in one of its indeterminates x1, ..., xn. If true is returned, then the function also returns a univariate version u of f and (the first) i such that f is univariate in xi. Note that there will only be ambiguity about i if f is a constant polynomial. The univariate polynomial u will be an element of R[x] with the same coefficients as f.'